# Application token for Sharepoint Search REST API

Tags: sharepoint

How can I configure my SPO to allow applications to use the [Sharepoint Search REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)? Additionally, what would the correct scope permission be? I have tried Sites.Read.All, but it does not work.

Currently it works for delegated tokens with the AllSites.Read permission, but there are use cases where getting a delegated token is not possible. Thanks